# Polymorphism in Meteor Templates

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Say I have a Meteor application which displays *widgets*. A *widget* can have one of several forms:

```
<template name="textWidget">
    <h1>{{myTitle}}</h1>
    <p>{{myTextContent}}</p>
</template>

<template name="imgWidget">
    <h1>{{myTitle}}</h1>
    <img src="{{myImagePath}}" />
</template>

<template name="listWidget">
    <h1>{{myTitle}}</h1>
    <ul>
       {{#each items}}
          {{> listWidgetItem}}
       {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Is there a good pattern for rendering a specific template given a record type?

Naively, I can do something like:

```
<template name="masterTemplate">
    {{#each widgets}}
        {{#if widgetType "text"}}
            {{> textWidget}}
        {{else}}
            {{#if widgetType "img"}}
               {{> imgWidget}}
            {{else}}
               {{if ... }} ... {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
        {{#/if}}

    {{/each}}
</template>
```

With a helper like:

```
Template.masterTemplate.widgetType = function(cmp) {
    return cmp === this.data.type;
};
```

**This seems like a very clunky and unflexible way to operate though. Am I missing an obvious library or design pattern for this use case?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
UI.registerHelper('widget', function () {
  var templateName = this.data.type + 'Widget';
  return Template[templateName].extend({ data: this });
});
```

and you can use it as follows:

```
{{> widget context}}
```

or

```
{{#with context}}
  {{> widget}}
{{/with}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late accept. I've been a bit busy lately.